# Second carousel on page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a second bootstrap carousel on my page. But i find problems. The carousel itself does move when waiting, but the carousel indicators(the 4 dots) don't work with moving around the carousel items. Can anyone help me out?

```html
<div class="testimonialblok">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="testimonialcarousel carousel slide" data-ride="testimonialCarousel">

    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-7"><img class="d-block testimonialfoto" src="#" alt="First slide"></div>
          <div class="col-5 testimonialtextcarousel">
            <h1 class="montserratblack textblue">Dummy text</h1>
            <span class="testimonialundertext"><img class="testimonialiconundertext" src="#"> Dummy text</span>


            <p class="testimonialtext opensanssemibold textblue">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temporut labore.
            </p>

            <p class="testimonialtext opensanssemibold textgrey">
              Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
            </p>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger montserratregular textuppercase btnonzevoordelen">Dummy text</button>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-7"><img class="d-block testimonialfoto" src="#" alt="First slide"></div>
          <div class="col-5 testimonialtextcarousel">
            <h1 class="montserratblack textblue">Dummy text</h1>
            <span class="testimonialundertext"><img class="testimonialiconundertext" src="#"> Dummy text</span>


            <p class="testimonialtext opensanssemibold textblue">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temporut labore.
            </p>

            <p class="testimonialtext opensanssemibold textgrey">
              Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
            </p>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger montserratregular textuppercase btnonzevoordelen">Dummy text</button>



          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-7"><img class="d-block testimonialfoto" src="#" alt="First slide"></div>
          <div class="col-5 testimonialtextcarousel">
            <h1 class="montserratblack textblue">Dummy text</h1>
            <span class="testimonialundertext"><img class="testimonialiconundertext" src="#"> Dummy text</span>


            <p class="testimonialtext opensanssemibold textblue">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temporut labore.
            </p>

            <p class="testimonialtext opensanssemibold textgrey">
              Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
            </p>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger montserratregular textuppercase btnonzevoordelen">Dummy text</button>



          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-7"><img class="d-block testimonialfoto" src="#" alt="First slide"></div>
          <div class="col-5 testimonialtextcarousel">
            <h1 class="montserratblack textblue">Dummy text</h1>
            <span class="testimonialundertext"><img class="testimonialiconundertext" src="#"> Dummy text</span>


            <p class="testimonialtext opensanssemibold textblue">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temporut labore.
            </p>

            <p class="testimonialtext opensanssemibold textgrey">
              Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
            </p>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger montserratregular textuppercase btnonzevoordelen">Dummy text</button>



          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-7"><img class="d-block testimonialfoto" src="#" alt="First slide"></div>
          <div class="col-5 testimonialtextcarousel">
            <h1 class="montserratblack textblue">Dummy text</h1>
            <span class="testimonialundertext"><img class="testimonialiconundertext" src="#"> Dummy text</span>


            <p class="testimonialtext opensanssemibold textblue">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temporut labore.
            </p>

            <p class="testimonialtext opensanssemibold textgrey">
              Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
            </p>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger montserratregular textuppercase btnonzevoordelen">Dummy text</button>



          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-7"><img class="d-block testimonialfoto" src="#" alt="First slide"></div>
          <div class="col-5 testimonialtextcarousel">
            <h1 class="montserratblack textblue">Dummy text</h1>
            <span class="testimonialundertext"><img class="testimonialiconundertext" src="#"> Dummy text</span>


            <p class="testimonialtext opensanssemibold textblue">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temporut labore.
            </p>

            <p class="testimonialtext opensanssemibold textgrey">
              Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
            </p>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger montserratregular textuppercase btnonzevoordelen">Dummy text</button>



          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-7"><img class="d-block testimonialfoto" src="#" alt="First slide"></div>
          <div class="col-5 testimonialtextcarousel">
            <h1 class="montserratblack textblue">Dummy text</h1>
            <span class="testimonialundertext"><img class="testimonialiconundertext" src="#"> Dummy text</span>


            <p class="testimonialtext opensanssemibold textblue">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temporut labore.
            </p>

            <p class="testimonialtext opensanssemibold textgrey">
              Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
            </p>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger montserratregular textuppercase btnonzevoordelen">Dummy text</button>



          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>
  </div>

  <ol class="carousel-indicators testimonialindicators">
    <li data-target="#testimonialIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#testimonialIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#testimonialIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#testimonialIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#testimonialIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#testimonialIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
```

This is my second slider. I also have a header slider, which consists of all the standard values of a bootstrap slider, i haven't made any changes there and that works fine. I have tried to reset this to blanc, but when using the same classes my indicators and stuff wont work.

Answer (score 0):

value of data-target in carousel indicators must be same as the id of carousel , in this case it shall  be data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"